# Custom configurations with C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, app-config, custom-configuration

I have an App.config with custom configurations

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="wsa" type="WSASRT.SRT.WSA.WsaConfig" />
  </configSections>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>

  <wsa>
    <src E="Foo@bar.com" CN="AnotherFoo" OU="AnotherBar" />
    <!-- More elements -->
  </wsa>

</configuration>
```

And the following mapping class

```
namespace WSASRT.SRT.WSA
{
    class WsaConfig : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("src")]
        public SrcElement Src { get { return (SrcElement)this["src"]; } }

    }

    public class SrcElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("E")]
        public string E { get { return (String)this["E"]; } }

        [ConfigurationProperty("CN")]
        public string CN { get { return (String)this["CN"]; } }
    }
}
```

And my Program.cs looks like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WsaConfig config = new WsaConfig();
        Console.WriteLine(config.Src.CN);
        Console.ReadLine();    
    }    
}
```

When I run it I get an empty string but I should get "AnotherFoo". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the first line as below so that you read it from your config file & not instantiate a new one..

```
WsaConfig config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("wsa") as WsaConfig;
```